# API em Laravel receber POST JSON e gravar em banco de dados

Tags: laravel

Irei receber através da API um JSON com esta estrutura:

```
{"leads":
  [{"id":"1",
    "email":"suporte@resultadosdigitais.com.br",
    "name":"Bruno Ghisi",
    "company":"Resultados Digitais",
    "job_title":"IT",
    "bio":"This is my bio",
    "created_at":"2012-06-04T15:31:35-03:00",
    "opportunity":"false",
    "number_conversions":"3",
    "first_conversion": {
      "content": {
        "identificador":"ebook-abc",
        "nome":"Bruno",
        "email_lead":"suporte@resultadosdigitais.com.br",
        "telefone":"99999999",
        "empresa":"Resultados Digitais",
        "cargo":"IT"
      },
      "created_at":"2012-06-04T15:31:35-03:00",
      "cumulative_sum":"1",
      "source":"source 1"
    },
    "last_conversion": {
      "content": {
        "identificador":"webinar-abc",
        "email_lead":"suporte@resultadosdigitais.com.br"
      },
      "created_at":"2012-06-04T15:31:35-03:00",
      "cumulative_sum":"2",
      "source":"source 2"
    }
  }]
}
```

Minha API deve receber estes dados e gravar em meu banco de dados, estou iniciando a utilização do Laravel e segui um tutorial do Vedovelli, a API está recebendo e gravando POSTs realizados sem ser no formato json porém qnd vou testar neste formato ele insere uma linha no banco de dados gravando somente o ID sem as demais informações.

Meu Controller está desta forma:

```
public function saveLead()
    {
        return Response::json($this->lead->saveLead(), 200);
    }
```

e o Model desta forma:

```
 public function saveLead()
    {
        $input = Input::all(); //pega todos os dados do input
        $lead = new Lead(); //criar um novo registro
        $lead->fill($input); //inclui todos os dados do input
        $lead->save(); //salva o input
        return $lead; //retorna o lead gravado
    }
```

Se eu acrescentar um dd($input); ele me mostra um array com os dados, porém na hora de gravar não insere os valores na base.

Desde já agradeço a quem conseguir me ajudar. :/

Comment: a sua estrutura do bd está seguindo as mesmas nomenclaturas do retorno do json? inclusive case-sensitives

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, em uma mesma action de um controller você pode receber um `request` tanto "normal" quanto em JSON. É isso mesmo? Sua action tem que ser inteligente o bastante para saber se o Request vindo contém o JSON ou não?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui resolver desta forma:

```
public function saveConversion()
    {
        $input = file_get_contents('php://input'); // Pega todos os dados do json
        $jsonDecode = json_decode($input); // Decodifica o json e transforma em objeto
        $leads = $jsonDecode->leads[0];

        $lead->id = $leads->id;
        $lead->email = $leads->email;
        $lead->name = $leads->name;
        $lead->company = $leads->company;
        $lead->job_title = $leads->job_title;
        $lead->bio = $leads->bio;
        $lead->opportunity = $leads->opportunity;
        $lead->number_conversions = $leads->number_conversions;

        $lead->save(); // Salva o input

        return $lead; // Retorna o lead gravado
    }
```